# WHM/cPanel SSL certificate and two different subdomains per machine/IP

Tags: ssl-certificate

I have two servers with WHM/cPanel installed - server1.mydomain.com and server2.mydomain.com, and I would like to install WHM SSL certificate on both machines (different IPs).

My question is do I need to get SSL certificate for wildcards or single domain and get that for each subdomain? Not sure how it will works with WHM when there are two different IPs for same domain just different subdomains.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be verified at SSL certificate provider regarding using it across multiple servers. In my case SSL certificate was assigned to a hostname, so wildcards will not work.

Answer (score 0):

There are can two configurations based on actual need.

**Wildcard SSL Certificates:**

Wildcard SSLs are of many types, some of them support even different IP address/servers as long as your domain name remains same upto unlimited number of sub-domains.

How URL looks: https://sub-domain.yourdomainname.extension

*When to use?*

- To product multiple sub-domains with single SSL certificate
- When Multiple sub-domains are part of single domain name (Generally used by companies)
- Examples, erp.yourdomain.ext, secure.yourdomain.ext, shop.yourdomain.ext, cp.yourdomain.ext, www.yourdomain.ext, yourdomain.ext etc.
- Certificate can be Domain Validation (Green Lock) or Business Validation (Green Bar)
- Costs approx. between $$ to $$$

If you are willing to secure, only few sub domains of your same domain name hosted across various servers, then probably SSL Certificate for single domain name/without wildcard can be best option, as you can buy couple of different certificates for each sub-domain from different/single vendors at very cheaper rates compared to wildcard.

Such SSL certificate can secure subdomain.domainame.ext, ex. www.domainname.ext and/or domainname.ext